# django manage.py raising ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: django

In attempting to run ./manage.py runserver or shell or any other command for that matter, I'm getting the error: You must define a 'default' database.

I'm running this in a virtualenv and settings.py includes DATABASE_NAME, along with Host, Port and Engine. Where is django expecting definition of the default database?

Here's the traceback:

```
(env)fox-ser01:common wmfox3$ ./manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 31, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/wmfox3/Sites/photo_project/env/src/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
  File "/Users/wmfox3/Sites/photo_project/env/src/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/wmfox3/Sites/photo_project/env/src/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/wmfox3/Sites/photo_project/env/src/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/wmfox3/Sites/photo_project/env/src/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/wmfox3/Sites/photo_project/env/src/django/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 46, in handle_noargs
from django.db.models.loading import get_models
  File "/Users/wmfox3/Sites/photo_project/env/src/django/django/db/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("You must define a '%s' database" % DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You must define a 'default' database
```

Comment: Did you check this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#databases? "The DATABASES setting must configure a default database; ..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DATABASE_NAME is deprecated since django 1.2 so if you're using newer version, you should use the [new way of defining databases](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase'
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. I see it now. I'm using http://github.com/ryanmark/django-project-templates. Unfortunately, the settings file installed by Paste used the deprecated version, and the requirements.txt file installed the django-trunk.

Comment: It seems that in 'simple project' they do use the new version: https://github.com/ryanmark/django-project-templates/blob/master/src/django_project_templates/templates/simple_project/config/settings.py_tmpl , but in 'django project' they don't. You can be nice and report an issue on https://github.com/garethr/django-project-templates/issues or be even nicer and fork them and fix that :)

Answer (score 4):

define db name is settings.py

DATABASE
Below is an example

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql',
        'NAME': 'xyz', # db name
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [`settings.DATABASES`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases).